# chrome shows the error TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined, even the promise was returned?

Tags: angularjs

i have the following code for save operation:

here is my angular service:  this already returns the promise

```
factory('customersaveService', function ($http, $q) {

    var factoryObject = {};

    factoryObject.SaveNewUserSrv = function(data) {

        var deffered = $q.defer();

        $http({
            url: 'CustomerTest1/SaveNewUser',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'cust': data }),
        })
        .success(function (d) {
            deffered.resolve(d);
        })
        .error(function (e) {
            deffered.reject(e);
        });
    }
    return factoryObject; 
});
```

in here the promise is returned. therefore it shoudl not throw the error

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

the error comes from the controller's code:

```
$scope.SaveCustomer = function (data)
    {
        if ($scope.ButtonText == 'Save')
        {
            $scope.message = "";
            $scope.submitted = true;

            $scope.User = data;

            console.log($scope.User);

            customersaveService.SaveNewUserSrv($scope.User).then(function (d) { <=== error line
                console.log('before success part');
                if (d == 'success')
                {
                    console.log('im in success part');
                    clearform();
                }
            },
            function (e) {

            });
        }
    }
```

why this throws the error when the promise was returned?

Answer (score 0):

1.Create service like below :
2.No need of $q service.

```
factory('customersaveService', function ($http) {
var factoryObject = {};
factoryObject.SaveNewUserSrv = function(data) {
  return $http({
        url: 'CustomerTest1/SaveNewUser',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'cust': data }),
    })
}
return factoryObject;
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
factory('customersaveService', function ($http) {
    var SaveNewUserSrv = function(data) {
        return $http({
            url: 'CustomerTest1/SaveNewUser',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
            data: { 'cust': data }
        });
    };
    return {
        SaveNewUserSrv: SaveNewUserSrv
    };
});
```

And in the controller, sure you inject the service `customersaveService`